# How to use arcmain to backup table with all his rows and without them(just structure)?

Tags: backup, teradata, utilities

I need to backup tables and be able to control what to store: full table or just its structure. Unfortunately, I didn't figure it out. So I looked [the official site](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/Storage_Management/B035_2412_071A/2412ch01.015.07.html), then tried to look [the full guide](http://www.info.teradata.com/eDownload.cfm?itemid=101680007), but it is so full unnecessary information.

So far I know how do it default way:

```
logon ZZZZ/YYYY,XXXX;

ARCHIVE DATA TABLE

(DATABASENAME.TABLENAME1),
(DATABASENAME.TABLENAME2),
(DATABASENAME.TABLENAME3),

RELEASE LOCK,

FILE=NVDSID1;

Example for a Restore of tables:
--------------------------------
logon ZZZZ/YYYY,XXXX;

COPY DATA TABLES

(DATABASENAME.TABLENAME11) (FROM(DATABASENAME.TABLENAME1)),
(DATABASENAME.TABLENAME12) (FROM(DATABASENAME.TABLENAME2)),
(DATABASENAME.TABLENAME13) (FROM(DATABASENAME.TABLENAME3)),

RELEASE LOCK,

FILE=NVDSID1;
```

But how can I specify what to dump as I asked before? And one more question: how to backup and restore views and procedures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dictionary backup will backup the definitions of all objects in the database, included the dictionary entries for stored procedures. If you specify a single object, then only that object's definition will be archived.

```
/* Dictionary Backup - Object Definitions only */
ARCHIVE DICTIONARY TABLES 
(DBNAME.TABLENAME1),
(DBNAME.TABLENAME2),
(...)

RELEASE LOCK,

FILE=NVDSID1;

/* Data Backup - Object Definitions and Data */
ARCHIVE DATA TABLES 
(DBNAME.TABLENAME1),
(DBNAME.TABLENAME2),
(...)

RELEASE LOCK,

FILE=NVDSID2;
```

Comment: Palley, Is that template suitable for arcmain version 14.1?